# MSAccess linked tables SQL Server "is not a valid name" error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, linked-tables

I have a third-party database that i want to link to but many table names are illegal - so i'm looking for a workaround, possibly including just keeping a duplicate database with acceptable (legal) naming structure,
 that anybody might have tried.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a SQL database you can [CREATE SYNONYM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) to alias an object/table name to something usable within Access.  Create synonms for all of the tables and then use those as your linked table names.

Comment: after further review i find that there are Primary Keys with invalid names. The External Data > ODBC Database > MSAccess "Link table wizard" will not run with such Key names (i seems it doesn't accept the form PK_dbo.keyname) -  the period . seems to be offensive